# Sort array order by average value in lists, print sorted array contains those lists

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

I want to create an array containing lists, each list contains integer numbers, sort those lists by their average value. I commented all the bugs in the code below.

Here is what I tried.

```
class solution
{
    public static void PrintArray(List<int> listArray, int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            //Bug: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of
            //type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition
            //for 'GetNumerator'
            foreach (int num in listArray[i])
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int size = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<int>[] listArray = new List<int>[size];
        string line;
        string[] data;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            line = Console.ReadLine();
            data = line.Split(' ');
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            foreach (string s in data)
            {
                int value = Int32.Parse(s);
//Bug: input s was not in correct format, sometimes it works, sometimes !work
                list.Add(value);
            }
            //This line will copy all the elements from list to listArray[i]
            listArray[i] = new List<int>();
            listArray[i].AddRange(list);
            //Clear the list
            list.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a programming language tag to your question

Comment: Your `PrintArray` function probably should get a `List<int>[]` as parameter (ie the array of all lists) and not just a single `List<int>`